# Sensors data not getting pushed into IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

I have setup one meshlium gateway with four waspmote(AC_1, AC_2, SC_1, EN_1) devices, I have configured IBM Bluemix configuration in IoT Platforms page in the meshlium web manager. The devices are getting created in the IBM Bluemix IoTF(Watson IOTF) devices section. But sensors data not getting pushed into IBM Bluemix IoTF, in the recent logs(events) section of each devices. Could please help me out to resolve the issue.

Current version of meshlium web manager is: 3.2.5 Model Kit
My sensors in the waspmote(AC_1) is sending data to meshlium in every 10 seconds.

Bluemix Config. here:
http://img4.imagetitan.com/img.php?image=13_meshlium_ibm_bluemix_cloud_connecttor_config.png

Devices got created in IBM Bluemix IoTF(Watson IOTF):
http://img4.imagetitan.com/img.php?image=13_meshlium_waspmote_devices_ibm_bluemix.png

Comment: Were you using this tutorial?  https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/bluemix-configuration-guide-for-meshlium/

Comment: @ValerieLampkin I have also followed the same ibm recipes(tutorial) link, it is creating the devices in bluemix watson iotf, but it is not getting the sensor data in recent events section of the device. help would be much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: It looks like you already posted on the libelium forum.  Please update if you get more details about what code the synchronization button runs so we can help from Bluemix side if necessary.